# With Vue.js, Is it possible to listen to all events emitted from numerous elements with a single event listener?

Tags: events, vue.js, vuejs2, single-page-application

I have a number of divs formatted to be buttons (20ish in total).

I'd like to have a single click listener (possibly on the parent div) that would listen for any/all clicks, and capture that specific divs innerHTML.

Other than vanilla JS or jQuery–in which I could listen to an id or class–is there a way with Vue.js?

Thanks!

Comment: https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/rGgrbb?editors=1010

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can accomplish this easily with an event bus:

```
var bus = new Vue()

// in component A's method
bus.$emit('my-event', { foo: 'bar' })

// in component B, C, D, etc created hook
bus.$on('my-event', function (data) {
  console.log(data)
})
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication