# Capture all click events inside Vue application

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to capture all click events triggered by the user inside my Vue.js application. My first step was to add an onclick listener to the `#app` div:

```
<div id="app" @click="onClickApp"></div>
// ...
<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      onClickApp() {
        // increment counter in vuex store
      }
   }
</script>
```

This captures all click events happening directly inside the App component. The issue is that I'm using a Bootstrap Modal (provided via BootstrapVue) and I need to capture the clicks inside it as well. This is not working at the moment, even if I set another @click listener on the `<b-modal></b-modal>` component (syntax for vue-cli).

This is what I also tried (in `main.js`):

```
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
  mounted: function() {
    this.$el.addEventListener('click', this.onClickVue)
  },
  beforeDestroy: function () {
    this.$el.removeEventListener('click', this.onClickVue)
  },
  methods: {
    onClickVue: function (e) {
      this.$store.commit(mutationTypes.INCREMENT_CLICKS)
    }
  });
```

Same problem, clicks inside the Bootstrap Modals are not firing a click event.

Comment: do you mean this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46899901/with-vue-js-is-it-possible-to-listen-to-all-events-emitted-from-numerous-elemen

Comment: Hm, thank you but I don't think so. This seems to be a solution for communicating between components via events, right? I just want to capture onclick events even in modals.

Comment: how about listening on a `document` ?

Comment: Is it feasible to set the listener and handler inside of your app `mounted` hook? Something like `document.onclick = (e) => { console.log("x: " + e.clientX + " y: " + e.clientY) }` should be easy enough to test...

Comment: Create a method for what you want to do `doSomething` and in a mounted add a listener and check if it works ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could only get this to work by using the `mouseup` event..

CodePen mirror: https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/PgKWRW?editors=1010

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    modalShow: false
  },
  mounted() {
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", e => {
      let m = `x: ${e.clientX} | y: ${e.clientY}`;
      console.log(m);
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.0-rc.11/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.0-rc.11/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app">
  <div style="margin: 5px 0px 0px 40px">
    <b-button @click="modalShow = !modalShow">Open Modal</b-button>
    <b-modal v-model="modalShow">Hello From Modal!</b-modal>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working! I combined it with the approach of @marvin-irwin and it's doing exactly what I want.

Comment: Beautiful! Glad you were able to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

A better answer is just adding ev to onClickApp, so do onClickApp(ev) inside your methods.

Now, you have access to the click event.

Answer (score 0):

This should work ;-)

```
- <div id="app" @click="onClickApp"></div>
+ <div id="app"></div>
// ...
<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      onClickApp() {
        // increment counter in vuex store
      }
   },
+  mounted() {
+    window.document.addEventListener('click'), this.onClickApp)
+  },
+  beforeDestroy() {
+    window.document.removeEventListener('click'), this.onClickApp)
+  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this (see my edit above), but still no clicks on the Modal are captured.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to test with Bootstrap Vue, but this might do.

TLDR: Create a plugin which will run whenever any of your components are instantiated.  Put a listener on the root element.

https://codesandbox.io/s/kxwz85pl65

```
const MyPlugin = {
  install(Vue, options) {
    Vue.mixin({
      mounted() {
        setTimeout(() => {
          let cb = this.$root.$el.onclick;
          this.$root.$el.onclick = (e) => {
            alert("element clicked");
            if (cb) {
              cb(e);
            }
          };
        }, 10);
      }
    });
  }
};
```

EDIT:

As of writing this `Vue Bootstrap` doesn't seem to allow click events for the modal itself, though elements inside of it can be clicked.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/kxwz85pl65

EDIT again, you can use set timeout if you really want to.  It's a bit of a hack though.

Comment: I really like your idea but the onclick isn't triggered in the modal, same effect as with my described functions in my question. If the page content is smaller than the viewport, no click events are triggered outside of the content (because `#app` is not stretched to viewport measures).

Comment: Thanks, but with the `setTimeout`I get 23 click events fired when clicking on one element. Furthermore, the Bootstrap Modal is still not reacting to clicks. I will check adding a separate `@click` to every modal element. I think I've done that already in the past but let's give it a try.